# How kill cp in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, kill

I see in:

```
ps aux
```

that exists process like:

```
cp  file.txt /home/file.txt
```

This file is very big.

I try to kill like:

```
kill -9 12345
```

12345 is pid. But without success. What else I can do? What the reason?

P.S.
12345  0.0  0.0  7890   704 ?        D    14:42   0:05 cp

Comment: Please give the full line of the process in `ps aux`.

Comment: kill should work.. do you copy from/to a special drive which can block/jam like CD or some network drive?

Comment: You can stop the process using CTRL+C. This will send a signal to cp stop.

Answer (score 3):

Just try CTRL+C in the terminal which cp works in. (I've assumed that you didn't send cp to background, which I don't do often.)

Comment: That's not significantly better or "stronger" than sending signals.

Answer (score 3):

You can't kill process if it waits for some kernel syscall. For example if drive is busy or filesystem is otherwise locked up then you can't kill this process. How does your process look like if you do "**ps -l**". **WCHAN** and **STAT** are attributes you need to look at.